# Finding location at every second

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the random waypoint model. I have a small doubt in that.
Random Way point model stats that :

The random waypoint model is

one of the most widely used mobility models. In the standard random
waypoint model, each node picks a random location as a destination
and moves towards the destination at a randomly selected velocity;
after reaching the destination, the node pauses for some random
amount of time and selects a new destination and repeats the
process.

So, I have a question. Suppose the random velocity is between 0.3-2.5 m/sec. I keep a random location first as 1,0 and the next destination would be 2,2.

So, I get that it takes me 2.4 sec to reach from 1,0 to 2,2 with 1 m/sec as velocity.

But, I need to find location at every second. I know that at 2.4 sec it is at 2,2 but how can I know that at the end of 1 sec, what would be the location.

Updated: Got one solution and tried that, but not getting answers

```
I multiplied it with that vector only, but i am not getting any near answer. 


Suppose, I have co-ordinates as: 1,0 and 2,2. 



The distance between them is 2.8 m. 


It takes 2.8 sec for velocity 1 m/sec. Thus, If I want to find location at 1 sec, then I applied the formula as :



    LookLen = sqrt(2^2+1^2)

    Distance travelled from 1,0 to 2,2 is 2.4. Thus with velocity =1 m/sec, the time is 2.4 sec. Thus, for t= 1 sec, the distance travelled with same velocity would be 1 m/sec.

Now, calculating the normalized vector. (2,2)-(1,0) = (1,2).

Thus, multiplying with the distance to be travelled : 

(1,2) * 1= (1,2)

So, Is (1,2) the new location ??
```

Comment: `how can I know that at the end of 1 sec, what would be the location` do it with pen and paper...then translate it to Java.

Comment: If the speed is constant, the location after 1 second should be the distance between the two points divided by 2.4 (in other words `1/2.4` times the total distance). This is a basic example of using ratios or proportions.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948809/compute-next-point-on-a-line-with-known-slope

Comment: @jahroy, Yes but how would i get it in x,y co-ordinate system.

Comment: Here's [one tutorial](http://www.1728.org/vectutor.htm) on adding vectors. Here's [another](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?313005-Point-add-a-distance-in-a-vector-direction). My guess is this was recently covered in the class you're taking...

Comment: @jahroy the last link does not give me appropriate answer with this. It is not for any course..

Comment: It doesn't show the exact steps you would follow, but it shows the general idea. You need to multiply the normalized vector by the distance you want to travel (ie `1/2.4`). Sorry I assumed you were sleeping in class!

Comment: @jahroy I updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your numbers are wrong... Shouldn't it be `LookLen = sqrt(2^2 + 1^2)` ??

Comment: @jahroy in the link the sqrt is done for 250, 148, 120...so i thought i should take all co-ordinates of the last point and do it.

Comment: That is because in the example the "look vector" is a vector that is relative to the origin. In your case you should use the distance formula to calculate the distance between the two points. Then you can find the distance travelled in one second by multiplying that number by `1/2.4`. Then multiply the normalized "direction vector" by that number and add it to your start point to determine the location after 1 second.

Comment: ... You can find the "direction vector" by subtracting the coordinates of the start point from the coordinates of the end point. This is a vector that represents the _direction_ that you are travelling between point A and point B. Don't forget to normalize this vector before scaling it by the desired distance (magnitude). Hope this helps!

Comment: You might find [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VectorCookbook.html) helpful.

Comment: @jahroy I edited, Is this perfect now ? or i have misunderstood something. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken and understood correctly, it should be like that:

It goes from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` with constant speed `V` which takes `t_total` sec and you want to know after the location of your point after `t_cur` seconds

Then after one sec, the position will be,

```
x_next = x1 + (x2-x1)/t_total*t_cur;
y_next = y1 + (y2-y1)/t_total*t_cur;
```

For your example, it'll be `x_next = 1+1/2.4 = 1.41 & y_next = 0 + 2/2.4=0.81`. the location after 1 sec is (1.41,0.81).

However, this is geometry question not programming etc.

**Correction**: Distance between points can be calculated like this:

```
dist = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2),
```

So, according to this function distance between `(1,0) and (2,2)` is **sqrt(1^2+2^2) = 2.23** **not 2.4**. So, calculate my answer accordingly. **instead of dividing to 2.4 divide to 2.23**